# How many positive integers less than $1000$ have digit sum equal to $n$ (where $n < 10$)?

Tags: summation

I was attempting a question that said "How many positive integers less than $1000$ have digit sum equal to $n$ (where $n < 10$)?"

My answer, which I have tested, was not in the solution, and so I was checking if I had made a mistake with my answer.

**My solution**

For $0$ to $99$, the sequence is as follows: $n$, $10 + (n - 1), \dots, 10 n$.

This can be rewritten further as: $(0*10) + n, \dots, (n*10) + 0$.

Therefore for $0$ to $99$, the number of positive integers whose digit sum is $n$ is the difference between $n$ and $0$, which is $n + 1$.

For $100$ to $199$, it will result in $n$, as there is the preceding $1$ adding to the total.

And so on...

Therefore the answer can be written as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (n + (1-k))$$

As for when $k = n$, (i.e. $100n$ to $100n + 99$) there will only be one solution ($100n$). After this it will stop.

**Given solution**

If the hundreds digit is $h$, the other two digits sum to $i = n - h$ and there are $i + 1$ possibilities. $i$ can be anywhere in the range $0$ to $n$, hence the total is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i + 1 = \frac{1}{2}(n + 1)(n + 2)$$

Comment: Give a more descriptive title.

Comment: For the range $0 – 99$, have you tested your formula $n-1$ for any values of $n$?  Does it give the correct result for $n=1$ or $n=2$?  What about when $n=20$?  If you have a formula that's full of undocumented exceptions, you will accumulate more and more errors when you apply the same formula to $100–199$, etc.

Comment: @ErickWong $n < 10$, which is why I can't test when $n = 20$, and I made a typo - the formula should be $n + 1$ in the range $0-99$

Comment: @Joe Ah, the question says $n>10$.  Is this also a typo?  If $n<10$ then this approach looks fine.

Comment: @ErickWong - that is a typo too (must be very tired)! Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Have you checked whether your answer and the given answer agree?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think "*My answer, which I have tested, was not in the solution*" is trying to point out that there was a disagreement.

Comment: @null Or it just indicates that the OP didn't recognise that his answer equals the given one, because of the different form.